# Multiple posts not visible using jQuery for RSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rss

I'm trying to build RSS feed and is working fine with displaying one post, I want it to display multiple posts.

Initially only post titles(panel-title) are visible and on click 've added toggle effect(jQuery) to show its content(data-content). It does fetch multiple posts(as object-shown in console) but isn't visible.

What i want?
--> to display multiple post titles initially and onClick display respective content body.

I think i should be using each() and append(), but I'm not sure how to do it.

you can check the whole code on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7sztc2rg/1/)

here is js file:

```
function blogRSS(url, container) {
var content = $('.data-content'); //console.log(content);

$.ajax({
url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
     console.log(data.responseData.feed); //it shows object of all fetched posts

     $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function(key, value) {
        var thehtml = '<h4><a href="' + value.link + '" target="_blank">' + value.title + '</a></h4>';

        $('.panel-heading').html(thehtml);
        $('.data-content').html(value.content);

    });
  $('.data-title').find('h4').addClass('panel-title');
 }
 });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to make this work:

You need to append the containing html for each item you add. To make as few changes to your script as possible, I did this using a var containing the structure for each item, then appending it before each item is added.

```
var itemLayout = '<div class="panel panel-default "><div class="data-title"><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down icon expand_icon"></div><div class="panel-heading"></div><div class="bkmark_icon"></div></div><div class="data-content panel-body"></div></div>';
```

Appending:

```
$("body").append(itemLayout);
```

Then you need to the say you add content, so you don't select every item, you can use `.last()` to make sure you only edit the item you just added.

```
$('.panel-heading').last().html(thehtml);
$('.data-content').last().html(value.content);
```

Now that the items are being added correctly, we need to make sure the buttons work everywhere. Since they're being added dynamically, your current `click` handler wont work, changing it to this will allow it to access dynamic elements:

```
$(document).on('click', '.panel-heading, .expand_icon', function() {})
```

And inside this, you need to make sure you're only selecting this items elements.

I've made some updates to your JSFiddle, take a look and it should do most of what you're after:

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7sztc2rg/3/)

This version will use a structure from the HTML file to clone and populate the feed, it's still dynamic elements, but this keeps your HTML in the HTML file:

[New fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7sztc2rg/4/)

Comment: thank you, it does work fine, but is there a way to keep the html or itemLayout (as you suggested) static i.e in html file (as before) and append only the related changes? Basically not creating layout dynamically from jQuery..

Comment: @kshah27 Well, if you want to add items in the way you are at the moment, it will need to be added dynamically. One way you could possibly make it a lot neater (though technically it's still dynamically creating them), would be to create a hidden `div` containing your structure, then clone it each time (rather than storing the structure in a var)

Comment: so to add a css property to main div as hidden and then make it visible every time is what you mean? umm maybe you can update the fiddle?

Comment: @kshah27 I've updated the answer, at the bottom there's a new fiddle using the `clone()` method.